# How do I use trig functions correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Given a direction in degrees and a distance, I am attempting to use the functions math.sin and math.cos to calculate the x and y distance a user would have to travel over a 5x5 grid.

A) Can someone tell me why my code is experiencing logic errors? It all checks out to me.

```
Please input the angle in degrees of the fire quickly!90
Please input the distance of the fire ~VERY~ quickly (input a number between 1 and 5)5
The fire is 1.000000 streets to the west of the firehouse!
The fire is 5 streets to the south of the firehouse!
```

It returns the wrong direction to go (south instead of north), and it instructs the user to go west 1 block. This is dreadful.

My second question is this:
How would I make it so the turtle would draw a blue line along the grid from the center point to whichever block was closest to the grid coordinates the user input.

CODE:

```
import turtle
import math
NUMBER_OF_LICENSES=10

def goodbyeMessage():
    print("Thank you for using the program!")

def getInfo():
    fire_Direction=math.degrees(float(input("Please input the angle in degrees of the fire quickly!")))
    fire_Distance=float(input("Please input the distance of the fire ~VERY~ quickly (input a number between 1 and 5)"))
    return fire_Direction,fire_Distance


def announceDirections(horizontolDirection,verticalDirection):

    if horizontolDirection < 0:
        print("The fire is %f streets to the west of the firehouse!" %abs(int(horizontolDirection)))
    elif horizontolDirection > 0:
        print("The fire is %f streets to the east of the firehouse!" %abs(int(horizontolDirection)))
    else:
        pass

    if verticalDirection < 0:
        print("The fire is %d streets to the south of the firehouse!" %abs(int(verticalDirection)))
    elif verticalDirection > 0:
        print("The fire is %d streets to the north of the firehouse!" %abs(int(verticalDirection)))
    else:
        pass

    if verticalDirection == 0 and horizontolDirection == 0:
        print("The firehouse is on fire!")


def giveDirection(fire_Direction,fire_Distance):
    horizontolDirection = round(fire_Distance * (math.cos(fire_Direction)))
    verticalDirection = round(fire_Distance * (math.sin(fire_Direction)))
    announceDirections(horizontolDirection,verticalDirection)




    return horizontolDirection, verticalDirection



def reportFire():

    fire_Direction,fire_Distance=getInfo()
    horizontolDirection,verticalDirection = giveDirection(fire_Direction,fire_Distance)



def drawHorizontal():
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(-300)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(500)
        turtle.forward(-500)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.forward(500)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(500)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(500)
    turtle.left(180)

def drawVertical():
    for i in range(5):
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(500)
            turtle.forward(-500)
            turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(-500) #Back to upper left corner which will be main drawing control point

def drawFireStation():
    #From main drawing control point
    turtle.penup()
    #225 instead of 250 so firestation circle is centered in middle of grid
    turtle.forward(225)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(-250)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(-225)
def drawGrid():
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.speed(0)
    drawHorizontal()
    drawVertical()
    drawFireStation()



def main():
    drawGrid()
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_LICENSES):
        reportFire()
    goodbyeMessage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's spelled "horizontal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trig functions expect their arguments to be in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)

You can use the `math.radians()` function to convert degrees to radians

eg:

```
fire_Direction = math.radians(fire_Direction)
horizontolDirection = round(fire_Distance * (math.cos(fire_Direction)))
verticalDirection = round(fire_Distance * (math.sin(fire_Direction)))
```

EDIT:

I noticed you are using math.degrees incorrectly here:

```
fire_Direction=math.degrees(float(input("Please input the angle in degrees of the fire quickly!")))
```

You should probably just change that one to `math.radians(...)` (which is the inverse of math.degrees)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input my friend,

I forgot to mention, that the user MUST input in degrees though.

EDIT:

NM. You are absolutely correct. I got it to work.

Comment: @user3187485 `math.radians(angle)` takes an angle in degrees and converts it to radians. That way you can use them in the trig functions provided in the `math` module.